# How do I assign a role after user clicks a link?

Tags: theming, users

I'm trying to get a behavior when a link is clicked, a role is applied to a user.

My use case is to allow a registred user to step into another type of user. Example is airbnb.com. You are a renter but once you click a certain menu link you become a host and get new menu items to then list your house.

I want to give permissions and access to certain areas of the site only when someone decides to unlock it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rules for that. The configuration can be({{}} are placeholders, do not use on the real values):

1. React on event "Content is viewed"
2. Condition: Data comparison (Parameter: Data to compare: [node:nid], Data value: {{NID from the node you're using to trigger this role activation}})
3. Action: Add user role (Parameter: User: [site:current-user], Roles: {{the role you want to add}})

Answer (score 0):

Flag module + @pedrorocha is quite a good tandem, instead of going to link, everything happen in one place, plus changing your link flag into different text ajaxly.

Comment: I agree with you, as I don't like much to base Rules on visiting some URL, cause it's easy to break, but if he doesn't have demand for a Flag in his structure, creating one only for this purpose would not be so good neither.
Anyway, any combination with Rules will help him.